# Could I get html of website without server knowing?

Tags: c++, http, web

Is it possible to get html of webpage without server knowing this. I mean without http request. Aren't all servers connected into internet. If I am right, it is just like filesystem: servers are just child folders and internet is the main folder(or a disk). So if i am correct the whole internet is pretty similar to a filesystem. So (only if i am right) it could be possible, to navigate to one server, and open some random html file in it, just like you open a file in a folder in File explorer. So I am asking: is it possible, and if it is how could I do it.

Comment: perhaps localhost?

Comment: Even in a local file system, file accesses are recorded.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that all servers are connected to the internet (although that's something of an oversimplification, the details aren't really relevant here). However, while those servers may have their own internal filesystem, you can't (generally speaking) browse them like a filesystem locally connected to your computer. Your computer and the server need to send data back and forth to get any files. The way this is done is with a protocol. HTTP (HyperText Transport Protocol) is one such protocol. If the server also accepts another protocol, such as FTP (File Transfer Protocol), you may be able to avoid using HTTP and get the files more directly, but in any case, the server still needs to send your computer data, which may be logged.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get html of webpage without server knowing this. I mean without http request.

Normally no, but under certain circumstances, yes. It's a http request (or whatever protocol the resource uses) still though.

Consider a corporate proxy. It downloads a page one time. The page may have a timestamp in it telling the proxy for how long it's allowed to cache it. All subsequent requests for that page from within the corporation may be served by the proxy server only - and the original server out there on the internet who published the webpage in the first place wouldn't know anything about it.

> Aren't all servers connected into internet

No.

Many servers providing services to individuals and corporations are not. Some (many) have internet access but do not listen for incomming requests. Others have no internet access whatsoever.

> If I am right, it is just like filesystem: servers are just child folders and internet is the main folder(or a disk).

Well... perhaps it could be viewed that way.

> So if i am correct the whole internet is pretty similar to a filesystem. So (only if i am right) it could be possible, to navigate to one server, and open some random html file in it, just like you open a file in a folder in File explorer.
> So I am asking: is it possible, and if it is how could I do it.

Kind of. You could use a webcrawler to scan a site but unless the server is improperly setup, you'll only have access to what the person behind the server wants you to have access to - and there are usually logs telling that person who (what IP number) did what.

Answer (score 0):

A web server is only going to be listening for HTTP requests and it will only deliver the pages it is setup to deliver. A server may support additional protocols like FTP but again it will only serve up the files it has been told to.

If you want access to a remote computers filling system then you will need a different protocol and access rights on the remote machine. Have a look at SMB 3.0 for ideas.